# Smarter way to gather data or a way to sort the data

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm pulling data from an sqlite table using `snip1`, this of course grabs each row containing the relevant `id` value. The `services` list now looks like `output1`.

I'd like to be able to sort the list of lists of tuples into a more managable data set. Merging all relevant id sets.
For example `[(10, u'80'), (10, u'443')]` becomes `{10: 80, 443}` and of course all other entries added to the same `dict`.

I'm having a hard time sorting the data. How would I compare items in the same list? The `example1` below shows the data cleaned up, but I'm uncertain on how to achieve a clean dictionary from it.

**snip1**

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM services WHERE id=?', (id_value,))
services = c.fetchall()
```

**output1**

```
[[(2, u'22')], [(3, u'25')], [(4, u'443')], [(5, u'443')], [(6, u'443')], [(7, u'22')], 
[(8, u'80')], [(9, u'443')], [(10, u'80'), (10, u'443')], [(11, u'80'), (11, u'443')], 
[(12, u'80'), (12, u'443')], [(13, u'443')], [(14, u'80'), (14, u'443')], [(15, u'25')]]
```

**example1**

```
data = [(2, u'22')], [(3, u'25')], [(4, u'443')], [(5, u'443')], [(6, u'443')], [(7, u'22')], 
    [(8, u'80')], [(9, u'443')], [(10, u'80'), (10, u'443')], [(11, u'80'), (11, u'443')], 
    [(12, u'80'), (12, u'443')], [(13, u'443')], [(14, u'80'), (14, u'443')], [(15, u'25')]]

for item in data:
    for i in item:
        print i  #output2
```

**output2**

```
(2, u'22')
(3, u'25')
(4, u'443')
(5, u'443')
(6, u'443')
(7, u'22')
(8, u'80')
(9, u'443')
(10, u'80')
(10, u'443')
(11, u'80')
(11, u'443')
(12, u'80')
(12, u'443')
(13, u'443')
(14, u'80')
(14, u'443')
(15, u'25')
```

Comment: There is no sense in `{10: 80, 443}`, do you mean `{10: [80, 443]}`?

Comment: Apologies, I mean a `dict` with a key and its relevant values. So yes if that is the correct format for it.

Comment: What is the purpose of this exercition?

Comment: The exertion do you mean? I will be comparing the data set against new data and updating it if it doesnt match.

Comment: Thank you all, thats what I love about coding. Theres always different ways to skin this cat :). I found vishes_shell's answer the most elegent so have chosen that as the `correct` answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with one line with using `dict` and `list` comprehensions

```
>>> data = [[(2, u'22')], [(3, u'25')], [(4, u'443')], [(5, u'443')], [(6, u'443')], [(7, u'22')], 
    [(8, u'80')], [(9, u'443')], [(10, u'80'), (10, u'443')], [(11, u'80'), (11, u'443')], 
    [(12, u'80'), (12, u'443')], [(13, u'443')], [(14, u'80'), (14, u'443')], [(15, u'25')]]
>>> output = {record[0][0]: [int(item[1]) for item in record] for record in data}
>>> output
{2: [22],
 3: [25],
 4: [443],
 5: [443],
 6: [443],
 7: [22],
 8: [80],
 9: [443],
 10: [80, 443],
 11: [80, 443],
 12: [80, 443],
 13: [443],
 14: [80, 443],
 15: [25]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {}
for item in data:
    d[item[0][0]] = []
    for i in item:
        d[i[0]] = d[i[0]] + [int(i[1])]
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert a list of tuples into a dictionary:

```
    list = [(10, u'80'), (10, u'443')]
    dict = {}

    for (i, j) in list:
        dict.setdefault(i, []).append(j)
```

This will give you:

```
    >>> dict
    {10: [u'80', u'443']}
```

You can then use pprint to print in a way that it is easy to compare dictionary items.

```
    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(dict)
```

The example only has one key but pprint will make a new row for each key similiar to what you have up there.

Comment: It's bad idea to call variables `dict` and `list`

Comment: If you intend to use default for dictionary values, you'd better to use `collections.defaultdict` data type.